# finding equidistant point in triangle with vertices a, b and c. language is c

Tags: c

I know the steps to calculate the circumcentre of a triangle but I couldn't understand how to implement it in my program. Please help. The vertices are a(2, 4) b(10, 15) c(5, 8)
Program
Step 1. Finding midpoint for a, bc, ca.
(x1+x2)/2
(y1+y2)/2
Step 2. Finding slopes for ab, bc, ca
M=(Y1-y2)/(x2-x1)
Step 3. Finding perpendicular bisectors slope
-1/M
Step 4. Finding equations.
Using midpoint and perpendicular bisectors slope
(Y-Y1)=m(x-x1).
Step 5. Solving and finding x and y.

Comment: You could start by spelling out just what those steps are.

Comment: Find the intersections of the three normals at the center of each vertice.

Comment: Sorry this is not a **I want a program** page.

Comment: Steps 1. Find midpoint of ab, bc, ca. 2. Find slope of ab, bc, ca. 3. Find slope of perpendicular bisectors. 4. Obtain eqns using midpoint and slope. 5. Solve those eqns.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Anyways thanks for your reply.

Comment: Midpoint: xm = x0 + 0.5 * (x1-x0); ym = y0 + 0.5*(y1-y0);

Comment: Is solving equations possible in c using math library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct point {
    double x, y;
} Point;

#if 0
ax + by = c
Ax + By = C

x = (c - by)/a = (C - By)/A
Ac - Aby = aC - aBy
(aB - Ab)y = aC - Ac
y = (aC - Ac) / (aB - Ab)
x = (Bc - bC) / (aB - Ab)
#endif

Point ans(double a, double b, double c, double A, double B, double C){
    Point ret = {FP_NAN, FP_NAN};
    double D = a*B -A*b;
    if(D == 0)
        return ret;
    ret.x = (B*c - b*C) / D;
    ret.y = (a*C - A*c) / D;
    return ret;
}

#if 0
(x-Ox)^2+(y-Oy)^2=r^2

(Xa-Ox)^2+(Ya-Oy)^2=(Xb-Ox)^2+(Yb-Oy)^2
(Xa-Ox)^2+(Ya-Oy)^2=(Xc-Ox)^2+(Yc-Oy)^2

2(Xb-Xa)Ox + 2(Yb-Ya)Oy + Xa^2-Xb^2+Ya^2-Yb^2 = 0
2(Xc-Xa)Ox + 2(Yc-Ya)Oy + Xa^2-Xc^2+Ya^2-Yc^2 = 0
#endif

Point center(Point a, Point b, Point c){
    return ans(2*(b.x-a.x), 2*(b.y-a.y), b.y*b.y - a.y*a.y + b.x*b.x - a.x*a.x,
               2*(c.x-a.x), 2*(c.y-a.y), c.y*c.y - a.y*a.y + c.x*c.x - a.x*a.x);
}

int main(void){
    Point a = { 2, 4}, b = {10, 15}, c = {5, 8};
    Point o = center(a, b, c);
    printf("(%f, %f)\n", o.x, o.y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot lot for the answer. But I've got the answer as (-230.5, 181.5) while the actual answer is (5.7, 9.0)

Comment: @Hinja check agein,  OA^2 = (5.7-2)^2 + (9.0-4)^2=38.69, OC^2 = (5.7-5)^2 + (9.0-8)^2 = 1.49, `(5.7, 9.0)` isn't equidistant point.

Comment: @Hinja `(5.7, 9.0)` is Centroid of triangle. `(a+b+c)/3`

Comment: thanks a lot. The code worked absolutely right. thanks a lot. They have given the answer wrongly in the source I referred to.